# SSRS suppressing page breaks on hidden items

Tags: hidden, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with multiple charts the are visible via expression and have page breaks. How do I eliminate dead space left from the hidden report items?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the visibility expression for the hidden report items to the entire row they appear on, rather than on just the items themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jim, however they do not reside in a row they are independent chart objects in the report body.